# use vbscript to get 32 bit floating point into binary byte or word representation

Tags: vbscript, floating-point, cpu-word, byte, binary-data

I don't know how to do two somewhat related task within vbscript (not vb)
-I need to break a 32 bit floating point into it's 4 byte binary representation.
-I need to break a 32 bit floating point into it's 2 word(aka16bit) binary representation.

For example,
65535.0 in format binary is 1000111011111111111111100000000
65535.0 in format hex is 477Fff00
65535.0 in format byte is 71, 127, 255, 0
65535.0 in format word is 18303, -256
[the last two is what i want to do]

reference: http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/32bit.html

Answer (score 1):

See [Converting a decimal value to a 32bit floating-point hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077718) for the solution in JavaScript. It shouldn't be too difficult to translate the code into Visual Basic.