# Reinterpret cast floating point number to integer

Tags: javascript, casting, floating-point, integer, typed-arrays

This question is probably "unusual", but I need to cast a float `Number` to an integer `Number`, without modifying its binary representation.

For example, the float `37.5` is represented by the bytes `0x42160000` (according to IEEE 754).
I need to reinterpret `0x42160000` as an integer, i.e. the number `1108738048`

How do I do this? I'm thinking there could be some bitwise tricks to accomplish this?

To be clear, I'm *not* looking for `Math.round` or `parseInt`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Float32Array) can come in handy here: http://jsfiddle.net/rtYrM/.

```
// create array which is specialized for holding 1 float value
var floatArray = new Float32Array(1);

// set the float value
floatArray[0] = 37.5;

// use its buffer (4 bytes for 1 float) and pass it to an array
// specialized for integers
var intArray = new Int32Array(floatArray.buffer);

// the integer array will interpret the buffer bytes as an integer,
// which seems to be just what you want
intArray[0] === 1108738048; //true
```

`intArray.buffer` will hold the same bytes as `floatArray.buffer`, but by not accessing it with the buffer but with the array itself, it will read those bytes as the type specified by the typed array: as integers for `Int32Array`, and as floats for `Float32Array`.

In this case (in base 10):

- `floatArray` is set to the value `[ 37.5 ]`.
- `floatArray.buffer` is automatically set to the values `[ 0, 0, 22, 66 ]`.
- `floatArray.buffer` is passed to a new integer array, `intArray`.
- `intArray.buffer` therefore contains the values `[ 0, 0, 22, 66 ]` as well.
- `intArray` contains the value `[ 1108738048 ]`, calculated with its buffer.

Comment: Awesome. Is this supported by all major browsers? I've never heard of Float32Array or Int32Array...

Comment: @Bart: I actually don't think so - it's brand new in fact. It works on Chrome - let me test for other browsers.

Comment: @Bart: Support in Firefox (at least Firefox 6), Chrome and Safari. Not in IE nor in Opera I'm afraid...

Comment: Okay, thanks. I guess I can do without IE and Opera for the time being.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work for Float64Array :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Javascript includes any mechanism for doing this. There's a method `java.lang.Float.floatBitsToIntBits()` in Java, so depending on your intended environment you might be able to make use of that. If all else fails, you might have to send the data back to the server to be converted. Alternatively, I've seen *attempts* at Javascript methods to do this conversion, but never one that was 100% complete and correct.

Comment: Well, an incomplete method is better than none at all. Could you show me some attempts?

Comment: There's this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077718/converting-a-decimal-value-to-a-32bit-floating-point-hexadecimal/3117567#3117567 . Despite the thread title, he's showing a conversion in the other direction.